# Fake proof for affineness for any morphism of schemes

Tags: fake-proofs, affine-schemes

It seems like a gave a "proof" of the following statement:

> Any morphisms of affine schemes is affine. $\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad (*)$

However, since affineness of morphisms can be checked locally, it would follow that every morphism would be affine, which is absurd. Can you please point out where I made a mistake?

---

**"Proof" of $(*)$**

Let $R \stackrel{\phi}{\to} A$ be a map of rings inducing 
$\text{Spec}(A) \stackrel{\psi}{\to} \text{Spec}(R)$. Since affineness can be checked on a cover,  let us use the cover 
$\{ D_R(f) \ | \ f \in R\}$
where
$D_R(f) = \{ \mathfrak{p} \subseteq R \ | \ f \notin \mathfrak{p}\}$.
I claim that 
$\psi^{-1}(D_R(f)) \ = \ D_A(\phi(f))$
for any
$f \in R$.
In deed:
$$
\psi^{-1}(D_R(f)) 
\ = \  
\{ \mathfrak{p} \subseteq A \ | \ \phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}) \not \ni f\}
\ = \ 
\{ \mathfrak{p} \subseteq A \ | \ \mathfrak{p} \not \ni \phi(f)\}\
\ = \ 
D_A(\phi(f)).
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is true that any morphism between affine schemes is affine, and it is also true that affineness can be checked locally on the *target*. It does not follow that every morphism is affine, and I don't know what argument you have in mind that would show this.

Comment: I don't remember either. It's a long time ago I did scheme theory. I think I had better delete this question.